# Does a Bangladeshi citizen need a transit visa for a short layover in France?

Tags: transit, schengen-visas, france, paris, bangladeshi-citizens

Hello Travel Community,

I am a Bangladeshi citizen planning to travel through France en route to another destination. My itinerary includes a short layover in a French airport, and I am trying to figure out if I need a transit visa for this part of my journey.

Here are the specifics of my situation:

Layover duration: The layover in France is 4 hours.
Airport details: I will be transiting through Charles de Gaulle Airport.
Stay in transit zone: I plan to stay inside the international transit zone of the airport.
Other visas: I hold a valid student visa for Canada.
Purpose of travel: My primary destination is Portugal for a conference to present a paper.

Given these details, could someone advise me if a transit visa is required for a Bangladeshi citizen under these circumstances? Also, if there are any recent changes in the French transit visa policy that I should be aware of, that information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to Portugal, I assume you have a Schengen visa. Which means you don't need anything else: you will enter the Schengen area in CDG, pass through passport control there, and transfer to the "domestic" (ie intra-Schengen) terminal for your next flight.

Depending on which airlines you are using, you may or may not have to pick up and check in again luggage, but since you state that you *plan to stay inside the international transit zone of the airport.* I suppose not.